# How to flush data from mysql.slow_log table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-slow-query-log

Hi i am working on MySQL version 5.5, can somebody please help me to clear/flush data from mysql.slow_log tables in mysql ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/577339/truncate-slow-query-log-in-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on linux

```
> mysql -uroot -p
> enter your password
> use mysql;
> delete from slow_log;
```

It will give you an error that you can't lock log tables. Work around is, run the following queries:

```
SET GLOBAL slow_log= 'OFF';
RENAME TABLE slow_log TO general_log_temp;
DELETE FROM `general_log_temp`;
RENAME TABLE general_log_temp TO slow_log ;
SET GLOBAL slow_log = 'ON';
```

Taken from ["DELETE old rows from Mysql General Log Table"](/q/21357177/)

**Update:**

You can truncate the table like
`TRUNCATE mysql.slow_log` as mentioned by Renato Liibke

Comment: when deleting records from slow_log getting error "Error Code:1556.You can't use locks with log tables."

Comment: got another error DELETE FROM mysql.general_log_temp Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences

Comment: unknown system variable "slow_log"?

Comment: @LennartRolland that's a table. select mysql database using `use mysql` and there is a table with name, you can verify it by using this query `show tables  like  '%slow_log%'` after selecting the mysql database

Answer (score 23):

You can avoid locking problems without disabling the slow log by using the built-in rotate function:

```
CALL mysql.rds_rotate_slow_log;
DELETE FROM mysql.slow_log_backup;
```

This will swap the 'slow_log' and 'slow_log_backup' tables, moving all of the data you want to clear to the non-locked 'slow_log_backup' table, which will happily take the DELETE FROM for data purging purposes.

You can also just invoke rotation twice:

```
CALL mysql.rds_rotate_slow_log;
CALL mysql.rds_rotate_slow_log;
```

Comment: Quite straightforward and useful approach, dude. I just didn't figure out why you got no up votes until now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was looking for!  would the question be tagged with RDS you  would get lot's of upvotes.

Comment: This is beautiful! Thanks for sharing this little gem, I had no idea RDS had their own stored procedures.

Comment: mysql> CALL rds_rotate_slow_log; Then the following error shows: ERROR 1305 (42000): PROCEDURE mysql.rds_rotate_slow_log does not exist; MySQL version 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20

Answer (score 18):

`TRUNCATE mysql.slow_log`

From Mysql Documentation:

TRUNCATE TABLE is a valid operation on a log table. It can be used to expire log entries.

Comment: shouldn't this answer be on the top?

Answer (score 0):

For me this works:

```
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log= 'OFF';
RENAME TABLE slow_log TO general_log_temp;
DELETE FROM `general_log_temp`;
RENAME TABLE general_log_temp TO slow_log ;
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'ON';
```